# How to convert the second column of a csv file to a list of floats?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, numpy, pandas

I have I csv file like this:

```
string, 3.54545,4.3434,3.34435543
string, 4.54545,67.3434,5.34435543
...
stringN, 5.54545,1.3434,9.34435543
```

How can I extract the first(strings) and the second column(floats) in two diferent lists with the csv module?.For example I would like to get something like this:

```
list1 = [string,string,...,string]
list2 = [3.54545,4.54545,..,5.54545]
```

Where `list1` is a list of strings and `list2` is a list of floats. I tried the following with pandas, the problem is that it took a lot of read the file:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test_dict.csv', header = None)

list1 = df[0].values.tolist()
list2 = df[1].values.tolist()
```

Thanks in advance, guys!

Comment: *the problem is that it took a lot of read the file:* what do you mean?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @TimCastelijns. The problem is that with pandas this task took a lot of time. What about another aproach for this (e.g. with numpy reader or with the csv module)?

Comment: Pandas is an optimized library for tasks such as these, why do you think doing it manually with e.g. the csv module would be any faster?

Comment: Thanks for the support I know what you mean. Our teacher assistant told us not to use pandas just csv or numpy. Any idea of how to aproach this task?.

Comment: How big is your file?

Comment: That's quite surprising, because I'd expect pandas to read three thousand lines in the blink of an eye. Maybe some other section of your code is the cause of the slowdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with the csv module like this, but as I remarked in my comments, don't expect it to be any faster than using pandas.

```
import csv

col1 = []
col2 = []

with open('test_dict.csv') as f:
  for row in csv.reader(f):
    col1.append(row[0])
    col2.append(row[1])
```

Comment: Do `col2` is a list of floats or strings?. Thanks for the help

Comment: col1 is a list of strings, col2 is a list of floats

Comment: Thanks but I guess `col2` is a list of strings, how can I convert it to a list of floats?. I expect multiplying it to another list that is why I would like to obtain it as a list.

Comment: @newWithPython, `float(row[1])`

Answer (score 2):

If you want the first two columns you can zip:

```
import  csv

with open("in.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    zipped = zip(*reader)
    s, f = list(next(zipped)), list(map(float, next(zipped)))
```

For python 2 use itertools.izip:

```
import  csv
from itertools import  izip

with open("in.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    zipped = izip(*reader)
    s, f = list(next(zipped)), map(float, next(zipped))
    print(s, f)
 (['string', 'string', 'stringN'], [3.54545, 4.54545, 5.54545])
```

Comment: thanks for the feedbacck. I got the following exception: `File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    s, f = list(next(zipped)), map(float,next(zipped))
ValueError: could not convert string to float:`

Comment: Do you have  header and is your data exactly as you have provided? Try removing the map float and see if you see any values that would casue an error

Comment: I dont have any header in the data. The data is exactly like is provided in the above example. Thanks for the support!

Comment: I have tested it with 3000 lines of similar data and get no error, try removing the map call and see if you see any strange output

Comment: When I removed the map I got this:`ValueError: too many values to unpack
`

Comment: I mean keep `next(zipped) ,next(zipped)` not completely remove! Just try not casting to float